# Implement Push notification from salesforce Marketing Cloud to React Native Mobile Application

Tags: react-native, push-notification, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I have to implement push notification in react native mobile application using Salesforce Marketing Cloud.But SFMC does not have any SDK or plugin for React Native.How to do I do that? Since I am new to React Native Can I please get a detailed explanation about this implementation?

Comment: Does somebody have any idea about how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

> Method 1

implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

if this still gives error then try

implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4"

> Method 2

If above doesn't work
Add one of the 2 lines in salesforcemarketingsdk gradle file in your project